# PayPal Payment TimeOut

Tags: paypal

We a developing a booking system using PayPal for payments.

If a payment is not made within a set time how can we prevent the payment from being completed if the set time has been exceeded?

When selling tickets to an event, we reserve the tickets until payment is made, but if payment is not made we need a way to cancel the transaction and allow the tickets to be sold to a different customer.

Hope someone can help!

Cheers. - Dave.